# SQL db account not recognizing db created as domain user

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a webapp in ASP.NET Core 2.0 using EF Core 2.0, code first, MSSQL server, IIS server. I develop under a domain account and all runs fine. Connstring:

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Production also runs fine when I enter my domain credentials in the IIS apppool identity, but that account cannot be used for production. So sysadmin created a mssql user (not domain user) specifically for the db. When I enter that in the connection string in appsettings in the published site, ASP complains about not finding any tables. When I enter it in appsettings in my dev environment and run Update-Database, all my tables are duplicated.

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

So my guess is that the newly made SQL Server account does not 'know' what database to use. This is the one thing I have no control over, so I cannot confirm or test this first hand. I was hoping anyone could give me some pointers as to how to make it so that the SQL user 'knows' to use the db I created as domain user.

Comment: `Initial Catalog` in your connection string tells you what database to connect to

Comment: I have specified it already.

Comment: It would clarify things if you posted a sanitized connection string.

Comment: tx for the tip, I have updated question accordingly

Comment: I suspect that in SQL Server you have to specify what database SQL user should access, but I have no access to it and have very little knowledge of db admin stuff.

Comment: By "tables are duplicated", do you mean you see two tables with the same name in different schemas?

Comment: Not quite familiar with this schema concept but I believe so, yes. I have tablenames with (dbo) after it and tables without (dbo). The (dbo) ones are created when I run Update-Database with the sql user in the connection string.

Comment: I think it would clarify things further if you posted a sample of what you see. Where do you see it? in SQL Server Management Studio?